# replace specific html in files from a BASH Script

Tags: html, bash, replace, sed

I have a number of HTML files that have the same section I want replaced:

```
  <div id="main-content" class="span12">
    <h1 id="404-page-not-found" style="text-align: center">404</h1>
    <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Page not found</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center"><a href=".">Home</a></p>
  </div>
```

I want to replace this code with `{{NAV}}`

I feel like I can do something like:

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find -name '*.html' | while read FILE; do
    sed --in-place -f replace.sed "$FILE"
done
```

replace.sed:

```
<my code above here>{
    r replacement
    d
}
```

replacement:

```
{{NAV}}
```

But I cannot get the code I want gone and replaced correct in replace.sed.

Can anyone think of a better way or how to format my code properly?

Comment: multi line replacement is not trivial with `sed`, you either replace newlines with some other delimiter to replace at once, or write a sed program to match line by line.  If you text is well formatted, `awk` might be a better option.

Comment: @karakfa the text is the same, exactly in every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `replace.sed` with this, it should work:

```
/<div id="main-content" class="span12">/ {  # If we match the first line
    :x               # Label to branch to
    N                # Read next line into pattern buffer
    /<\/div>$/! bx   # If we don't match the closing tag, branch to x
    c \{{NAV}}       # Replace the pattern buffer with {{NAV}}
}
```

This works if the first and last line are enough to uniquely identify the piece of html to replace. If you want to exactly match the whole snippet, you could do it like this:

```
/^<div id="main-content" class="span12">/ {
    N
    /<h1 id="404-page-not-found" style="text-align: center">404<\/h1>/! b
    N
    /<p style="text-align: center"><strong>Page not found<\/strong><\/p>/! b
    N
    /<p style="text-align: center"><a href=".">Home<\/a><\/p>/! b
    N
    /<\/div>$/ c \{{NAV}}
}
```

This one works as follows:

- If the first line is matched, load the next line (`N`)
- If the pattern space now doesn't match the second line, branch to the end of the cycle (`b`) and print the pattern space, else load the next line
- Repeat for lines three and four
- If now the closing tag is at the end of the pattern space, replace the whole pattern space with `{{NAV}}`, else just print it

Comment: I am trying the first one and getting: `$ /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed -i .bak -f replace.sed 404.html
sed: 3: replace.sed: extra characters at the end of N command`

Comment: @Jason Which version of sed are you using? Some flavours don't play well with comments.

Comment: I am using whatever is part of OS X 10.11. I'm sorry `man sed` doesn't seem to have a version flag so I can double check. I can try to remove the comments too

Comment: FYI, the second one gives me a similar error but with `h` and not `N`

Comment: @Jason `sed --version` usually shows the version. And there is no `h` in the second one...?

Comment: @Jason Hmm, maybe it's not escaping the `<` properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100493/discussion-between-jason-and-benjamin-w).

Comment: This indeed works. I appreciate the help and understanding.